# UPSERT with non-unique index

Tags: mysql, concurrency, sql-insert, upsert, on-duplicate-key

I need to implement concurrent-safe [UPSERT](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) using a non-unique key and avoid unnecessary auto-increment of ID.

Traditional [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) doesn't work for me, so I'm performing:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT 1, 2, 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table
                    WHERE col3 = 'value3'
                      AND col4 = 'value4'
                      AND col5 = 'value5')
```

then if it results in no row inserted, I'm performing:

```sql
UPDATE table
   SET col1 = col1 + 1,
       col2 = MAX(col2, 2)
 WHERE col3 = 'value3'
   AND col4 = 'value4'
   AND col5 = 'value5'
```

There's an index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON table (col3, col4, col5)
```

It is non-unique as there are legacy data that does not allow me to declare it unique.  Newer records, however, should not have duplicated `(col3, col4, col5)` rows.

Unsurprisingly, using the given INSERT statement I'm getting mixed results trying to execute it concurrently from two sessions.  I can see the second session blocking until the first one commits its transaction, but then the second transaction is also able to insert a new row sometimes (or sometimes it achieves the expected of avoiding to insert a duplicate `(col3, col4, col5)` row).

I'm currently performing manual unique-check after the insert:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM table
 WHERE col3 = 'value3'
   AND col4 = 'value4'
   AND col5 = 'value5'
```

but I've also tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT 1, 2, 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table
                    WHERE col3 = 'value3'
                      AND col4 = 'value4'
                      AND col5 = 'value5'
                      FOR UPDATE)
```

which appears to work with the examples I'm always getting a duplicate `(col3, col4, col5)` row, otherwise.  Is the given `FOR UPDATE` usage reliable for the purpose of ensuring no duplicate `(col3, col4, col5)` row will be inserted?

I'm using READ-COMMITTED transaction isolation.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0.13 and higher supports functional key parts that index expression values rather than column or column prefix values. ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html))

Because you have a unique field, i am assuming this is `col`, you can add an index like:

```
CREATE unique INDEX idx2 ON `mytable` ((col1>42),col3, col4, col5);
```

Where `42` should be the next auto-increment for `col1`.

Newly create records will be unique on the 3 columns, without affecting your 'old' data.
It is even possible to update the old data (as long as `col1`<=42).

Comment: I would love to use functional indexes in other instances, but I'm stuck with MySQL 5.7 for the time being.  Additionally, new legacy format data may appear for some time after the new aggregations (basically) are already in place.